# Is there a way to use jinja2 in an android hybrid app?

Tags: jinja2, hybrid-mobile-app, jasonette

I have a mobile android hybrid app that mimics a webapp.
In the webapp I use flask and jinja2 to create the HTML pages.
In the mobile android app I have an non-template html file that loads the javascript files from the local mobile device, so it can work offline.
There is no webserver or flask in the android app, so the html pages with jinja2 do not present correctly.

Is there a way to use jinja2 in an android hybrid app?
If not, what is the best way to adjust the jinja2 html files.

- Should I rewrite an equivalent non-template html file?
- Or is there another templating language that can be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by having a second version of the html file (e.g. extended_app.html) which combines the templated html file (extended.html) and the base html (base.html) embedded within it explicitly, thus avoiding the need to have jinja2 when working in the mobile app.